# Animated auto-hide ApplicationControlBar

Tags: apache-flex

Anyone know how to create animated auto-hide on ApplicationControlBar just like Windows's taskbar?
I'm totally new on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with doing this is that on Windows, you have a 'lower bound'--also known as the bottom of the screen which is used to trigger the display of the task bar based on the mouse location.

In a browser based app, you don't have that spot which is easy for the user to roll their mouse over.

That said, if you're still adamant, you should be able to put something together easily using the mouse over events to swap the visibility of the ApplicationControlBar and then you can use show / hide effects to display the control bar.